# Restrict browsing of parent directories in Apache auto-indexing

Tags: apache

I would like to have any directory auto-indexing by Apache not display a link to the parent directory.  In my current setup, I have only enabled access to all subdirectories, thereby implicitly denying access to the one parent directory of each of those subdirectories.  Unfortunately, the auto-indexing is still displaying a link to the parent directory even though clicking on that link results in a 403 response.

Answer (score 0):

```
IndexIgnore ..
```

You can read more on the **[`Auto-Index` options](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_autoindex.html#indexignore)** on Apache Docs.